# Date format command

Tags: command-line, date

I have a requirement to append timezone value in the below format at the end of milliseconds, an example follows:

> ```
> 2018-01-07T14:30:03.832-0700
> ```

I need the Unix command to get the required format.

Comment: Where does the data come from, a file? What is the format of that file? Are you just wanting to append the string `-0700` to the end of the timestamp? Where is the output going?

Comment: What does it look like now? Where is if from? (it looks fine to me, you will have to explain more).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is posible to get the ISO8601 time format with GNU date:

```
$ date -Iseconds
2018-07-01T06:57:25-0700
```

However, to get the time with milliseconds you neef to specify the detailed string. Try:

```
$ date +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3N%z'
2018-07-01T06:57:28.457-0700
```

Comment: Since date is based on `strftime()` and that uses a `struct tm` as input, the granularity is seconds only. `%N` is a nonstandard extension that is implemented inside your `date` clone.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU or ast-open `date`:

```
$ date +%FT%T.%3N%z
2018-07-01T13:44:07.043+0100
```

(GNU `date` (not GNU `strftime`) also supports `%:z` for `+01:00`, `%::z` for `+01:00:00`¹ and `%:::z` for `+01`/`+01:30`/`+01:30:01` (as many extra `:xx` as necessary)).

In `ksh93`:

```
$ printf "%(%FT%T.%3N%z)T\n"
2018-07-01T13:44:07.043+0100
```

In `zsh`:

```
$ zmodload zsh/datetime
$ echo $EPOCHREALTIME | IFS=. read s ns
$ strftime %FT%T.$ns[1,3]%z $s
2018-07-01T13:44:07.043+0100
```

Portably (the hard part is the milliseconds here, not the timezone offset which you can get with `%z` in anything that wraps the standard² `strftime()` function like `date`), you could try `perl`:

```
perl -MTime::HiRes=gettimeofday -MPOSIX -le '
  ($s, $us) = gettimeofday;
  $ms = sprintf("%03d", $us/1000);
  print strftime "%FT%T.$ms%z", localtime $s'
```

---

<sup>¹ Yes, it's possible to have TZ offsets with non-zero seconds, like in `TZ='OFF00:00:01' date '+%Z %::z'`. For real-life timezones, that only applies for dates in distant (pre-Unix) times. See for instance `TZ=Europe/Amsterdam date -d '90 years ago' '+%F %::z'`</sup>

<sup>² Note however that while `%F` and `%z` are specified in POSIX `strftime()` (at least since SUSv3), they are not in the POSIX specification of the `date` utility (I don't know of any current system where `date` doesn't support them though)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Add `%z` to your time format.  Example:

```
$ date
Sun Jul  1 04:55:02 EDT 2018
$ date '+%z'
-0400
$
```